# Trigger Alert (https://material-ui.com/components/alert/#alert) from the lowest Hierarchical component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, alert

So the thing is a normal alert works like `Alert("msg to be displayed");` but I want to use the Alerts of material UI. They Work like returning a JSX component. `<Alert severity="success">This is a success alert — check it out!</Alert>`.
I was able to implement this but the problem is the place where I pass the JSX, It occurs in that Grid, which is not at the Top of the web-app. So how to overcome this such that I can just pass Alert from anywhere and it pops at top area of the app.

I've 4-5 Hierarchical components and I tried to pass the Alert trigger through props from each of the component, it worked but It is a lot of hassle .

Comment: can you please share the sample component with problem of what is happening and what is desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

-Define a variable called alert in the state of your index file

-Create a function called setAlert that makes the alert equal to the jsx you need

-Create another function hideAlert that sets the alert to an empty string or whatever you might find convenient to not display the alert

-Place the alert variable in the return of your main app component.

-Make sure the alert is placed inside a div with position absolute and correct styling.

-Pass the setAlert and hideAlert functions via context or simply by passing props to all the other components.

Voila!